# How to get the all issues/defect list of Amazo Corretto 8.382

Tags: java-8, corretto

[image]Guys I’m working on my project and decided to upgrade the jre version to 1.8.382 do my team wants to do the Anomaly review for this.
How will I get the list of all active issues. For example in the image there it shows only one issue fixed so I want to know what other issues are there that is still pending.